# Replace duplicated frames with interpolated frames (using ffmpeg)

Tags: ffmpeg, duplicates, interpolation

I have some videos with duplicated frames and now the video looks not smooth. You can imagine this like in the tv show "the dragon prince" (at least the first season). See here an example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zHVjLhDWWFQ

Basically I want to try to fix this in my videos.

I thought like **removing the duplicated frames and add some interpolated frames instead** the duplicated/missing one. More precisely, in my opinion it could be best to *"just" replace the duplicated frames with interpolated one*.

**I tried to remove the duplicated via:**

`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vf mpdecimate,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB output.mkv`

This worked well, however the video was not sync with the time any longer.

**So I tried to add the new frames now:**

`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter "minterpolate='mi_mode=mci:mc_mode=aobmc:vsbmc=1'" output.mkv`

This did not work as expected.

**Maybe doing it "afterwards" is wrong, so I tried to combine both:**

`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter:v "minterpolate=fps=24:mi_mode=mci:mc_mode=aobmc:me_mode=bidir:vsbmc=1" output.mkv`

Actually I played around with this for some hours but I couldn't make it work.
Any idea how to solve this issue?

P.S. I am ffmpeg beginner.